# On the identification of $\mathbb R^4\wedge\mathbb R^4$ with the set of antisymmetric matrixes in $\mathbb R^{4\times 4}$

Tags: exterior-algebra

In view of the ususal definition of the [electromagnetic field tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Relationship_with_the_classical_fields), I assume that $\mathbb R^4\wedge\mathbb R^4$ can be identified with the subset of $\mathbb R^{4\times 4}$ consisting of antisymmetric matrices. Can someone tell me the precise form of this isomorphism$$\mathbb R^4\wedge\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^{4\times 4}_{\mathrm{antisymmetric}}$$i.e. can someone either explain to what matrix $x\wedge y$ is mapped for $x,y\in\mathbb R^4$ or to what matrices the elements of the standard basis are mapped?

Comment: You are missing half of the basis 2-forms.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Thank you very much for the remark, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basis of $\mathbb{R}^4\wedge\mathbb{R}^4$ is
$$\{e_1\wedge e_2,e_2\wedge e_3,e_3\wedge e_4, e_4\wedge e_1, e_2\wedge e_4, e_1\wedge e_3\}. $$
You can associated to $e_i\wedge e_j$ the matrix with $1$ on position $(i,j)$, $-1$ on position $(j,i)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that $$\{e_i\wedge e_j:i<j \}$$is considerd the standard basis, so did you mean to write $e_1\wedge e_4$ instead of $e_4\wedge e_1$?

Comment: Yes you can use the "standard" basis, you have the idea :D

Comment: I thought this changes the isomorphism, but I was wrong. Thanks! I will ask a new question for the uniqueness part.