# Is the usual identification of $\mathbb R^n\wedge\mathbb R^n$ with antisymmetric matrices in some sense unique/a natural isomorphism?

Tags: exterior-algebra

Let $M_{ij}\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be the matrix with $1$ on position $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere and let $V\subset\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be the subspace of antisymmetric matrices. Then the "standard" isomorphism between $\mathbb R^n\wedge\mathbb R^n$ and $V$ maps $e_i\wedge e_j$ to $M_{ij}-M_{ji}$ (this was explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4426020/572841)).

I guess that this isomorphism is in some sense unique, i.e. this a "natural" isomorphism, but I don't know what "natural" means in this context. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural here has a precise meaning in the language of categories but that may not be appropriate here. Instead you can think of it as meaning "coordinate independent." This seems a little weird because the map you defined is written in terms of coordinates but you actually don't need to do this.

The coordinate-free definition of the map looks like this. Define a map $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\wedge\mathbb R^n\to V$ by $$\varphi(v\wedge w)(u)=(v\cdot u)w-(w\cdot u)v.$$ If you write this map in coordinates you'll see that it's actually the same as the one you defined. The advantage to my definition is that I make no use of the fact that we're in $\mathbb R^n.$ This definition works the same way for every inner product space $V,$ and this is what earns it the descriptor "natural."

Comment: I don't quite understand yet (nevertheless, +1): I thought that given a vector space $V$, $V\wedge V$ is a vector space $W$ together with a function $V\times V\to W$, i.e. no inner product is involved in the definition. However, the formula$$\varphi(v\wedge w)(u)=(v\cdot u)w-(w\cdot u)v$$ clearly involves an inner product.

Comment: There is no inner product necessary to define the vector space $V\wedge V,$ however to identify it with the space of skew-symmetric linear transformations then it is necessary. This is because the definition of skew-symmetric requires an inner product in the first place.

Comment: "This is because the definition of skew-symmetric requires an inner product in the first place" - Could you please tell me the definition or where I can find it?

Comment: Well, a linear transformation $A:V\to V$ is skew symmetric if $A=-A^T.$ But for this you need to say what you mean by $A^T.$ It's defined as the transformation $B$ such that $(Av,u)=(v,Bu)$ for all $u,v\in V.$ So really it should be that $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$ with respect to this particular inner product, and similarly the term should be that $A$ is skew-symmetric with respect to this particular inner product.